# How to handle auto logout after 5 minutes when app goes to background in android

Tags: android, session, logout

I'm doing banking application after 5 mins activity should go to the login screen, I referred many links and implemented,
It's working when the app is in the foreground, I'm calling timer and checking after 5 mins I'm redirected to login screen.

But when the app is in the background how to handle, if I login same timer and redirected to login page means automatically its opened.it should not open right.

In background itself, it should move to login screen right. Please help me to solve my problem.

I referred this link:https://gist.github.com/dseerapu/b768728b3b4ccf282c7806a3745d0347

Comment: I check your referred link and analysis the code. its only execute in foreground state only.Can u explain background means which case its home button pressed, back button, are recent apps button. if u cleared your app in the recent apps use background service and call the timer function in service.

Comment: Hi if i am not wrong i will give you one suggestion .. create a never ending background process it will work when app is foreground and background also .. if your app is in background just update the boolean as appIsInBackground and maintain it's on Session once re open the application u will the boolean login or not trigger where ever you want...

for your kind reference i am attaching the background never ending process examples in android ...

https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: if app goes to background that menas recent app.. after 5mins if i open it should go to login right ?? Like SBI banking application.

Answer (score 2):

One of mine application is successfully working on auto logout after 5 minutes whether app is in background or foreground state.

To create auto logout for 5 minutes first create all class as below:

> ApplockManager

```
public class ApplockManager {
    private static ApplockManager instance;
    private DefaultApplock currentAppLocker;

    public static ApplockManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ApplockManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void enableDefaultAppLockIfAvailable(Application currentApp) {
        currentAppLocker = new DefaultApplock(currentApp);
    }

    public void startWaitThread(Context context){
        currentAppLocker.startWaitThread(context);
    }

    public void updateTouch(){
        currentAppLocker.updateTouch();
    }

    public void setStopTrue(){
        currentAppLocker.setStopTrue();
    }

    public void setStopFalse(){
        currentAppLocker.setStopFalse();
    }

}
```

> DefaultApplock

```
public class DefaultApplock implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        final String TAG = DefaultApplock.class.getSimpleName();

        private Application mCurrentApp;

        private long WAIT_TIME = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        private Waiter waiter;
        private Date mLostFocusDate;

        public DefaultApplock(Application app) {
            super();
            mCurrentApp = app;

            //Registering Activity lifecycle callbacks
            mCurrentApp.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            mCurrentApp.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            // for UserInactivity

            // for Screen lock
            if (shouldShowUnlockScreen()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "time over");

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Log.d(TAG, "changing mLostFocus to null");
                mLostFocusDate = null;
                activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        }

        private boolean shouldShowUnlockScreen() {
            Boolean isvalid = false;
            if (mLostFocusDate == null) {
                isvalid = false;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timeout -&gt;"+timeSinceLocked());
                if (timeSinceLocked() >= (WAIT_TIME/1000)) {
                    isvalid = true;
                } else {
                    mLostFocusDate = null;
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, isvalid.toString());
            return isvalid;
        }

        private int timeSinceLocked() {
            return Math.abs((int) ((new Date().getTime() - mLostFocusDate.getTime()) / 1000));
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            /*if(waiter!=null) {
                waiter.stopThread();
            }*/
            mLostFocusDate = new Date();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }

        public void startWaitThread(Context context){
            /*if(waiter!=null) {
                waiter.stopThread();
            }*/
            waiter = new Waiter(context, WAIT_TIME);
            waiter.start();
        }

        public void updateTouch() {
            if(waiter!=null) {
                waiter.touch();
            }
            mLostFocusDate = new Date();
        }

        public void setStopTrue() {
            if(waiter!=null) {
                waiter.setStopTrue();
            }
        }

        public void setStopFalse() {
            if(waiter!=null) {
                waiter.setStopFalse();
            }
        }

    }
```

> Waiter

```
public class Waiter extends Thread
{
    private static final String TAG=Waiter.class.getName();
    private long lastUsed;
    private long period;
    private boolean stop = false;
    private Context mContext;
    SessionManager session;

    public Waiter(Context context,long period) {
        this.period=period;
        stop=false;
        mContext = context;
        session = new SessionManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void run() {
        long idle=0;
        this.touch();
        do
        {
            idle = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUsed;
            if(idle > period)
            {
                idle=0;
                // Perform Your desired Function like Logout or expire the session for the app.
                stopThread();
            }
        }
        while(!stop);
        Log.d(TAG, "Finishing Waiter thread");
    }

    public synchronized void touch() {
        lastUsed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public synchronized void setStopTrue() {
        stop = true;
    }

    public synchronized void setStopFalse() {
        stop = false;
    }

    public synchronized void forceInterrupt() {
        this.interrupt();
    }

    public synchronized void setPeriod(long period)
    {
        this.period=period;
    }

    public synchronized void stopThread() {
        stop = true;
        session.logoutUserInBackgroundOrForeground(mContext);
    }

    public synchronized void startThread() {
        stop = false;
    }

}
```

> SessionManager

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyAutoLogoutAppPref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     */
    public void createLoginSession() {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setIsLogin(boolean login) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, login);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void logoutUserInBackgroundOrForeground(Context context) {
        setIsLogin(false);
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

> MyAutoLogoutApp

```
public class MyAutoLogoutApp extends Application {
    public static MyAutoLogoutApp myAutoLogoutApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myAutoLogoutApp = this;
        ApplockManager.getInstance().enableDefaultAppLockIfAvailable(this);
        ApplockManager.getInstance().startWaitThread(myAutoLogoutApp);
    }

    public void touch() {
        ApplockManager.getInstance().updateTouch();
    }

    public void setStopTrue() {
        ApplockManager.getInstance().setStopTrue();
    }

    public void setStopFalse() {
        ApplockManager.getInstance().setStopFalse();
        ApplockManager.getInstance().startWaitThread(MyAutoLogoutApp.myAutoLogoutApp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

> BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        MyAutoLogoutApp.myAutoLogoutApp.touch();
    }

}
```

Finally your every activity must extends BaseActivity so when user touches any where then onUserInteraction() method will fire and timer will reset and it will work for both background and foreground scenario.

Comment: I tried your code but app is in background i mean recent app,that time also automaticallly its opening login screen after 5 mins, its wrong right,when user click that time it should go login screen

Comment: do you want to start timer after the app is in background (recent) state?

Answer (score 0):

**using Global Key**

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

**add this is materialapp**

```
MaterialApp(
navigatorKey: _navigatorKey, 
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 
initialRoute: '/',

          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{

            "/":(BuildContext context) => new Splash(),

            "/login": (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(),

            '/main_menu': (BuildContext context) => MenuMainScreen(),
          },// MenuMainScreen(),
        ),
```

then use it

```
_navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```